# Desmembrar variavel, pegando parte do texto

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis

Tenho um select múltiplo que salva o seguinte formato no banco de dados:

```
1-Azul,2-Verde,3-Vermelho,4-Preto,5-Branco
```

Agora eu preciso desmembrar essa variável para poder mostrar o resultado, porém preciso além de retirar a virgula, pegar apenas a parte que fica depois do "-" de cada cor.

Ex:

```
Azul
Verde
Vermelho 
Preto
Branco
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer funcionar da seguinte maneira caso mais alguem venha a ter o mesmo problema:

```
<?php

$string = $ativos_u; //aqui eu pego string vinda do BD
$array = explode(',', $string); //aqui explodo as virgulas que separam

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
list($cod, $ativo) = explode("-", $array[$k]);
echo '<a href="principios-ativos.php#ativo'.$cod.'">'.$ativo.'</a>';
} //Depois faço um foreach com uma lista para separar o codigo do nome e exibo cada um separadamente usando uma lista.

?>
```